# How do I process a range in slices in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, slice

I understand that the preferred way to iterate in Rust is through the `for var in (range)` syntax, but sometimes I'd like to work on more than one of the elements in that range at a time.

From a Ruby perspective, I'm trying to find a way of doing `(1..100).each_slice(5) do |this_slice|` in Rust.

I'm trying things like

```
for mut segment_start in (segment_size..max_val).step_by(segment_size) {
    let this_segment = segment_start..(segment_start + segment_size).iter().take(segment_size);
}
```

but I keep getting errors that suggest I'm barking up the wrong <del>type</del> tree. The docs aren't helpful either--they just don't contain this use case.

What's the Rust way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`chunks`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) (or [`chunks_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_mut) if you need mutability):

```
fn main() {
    let things = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

    for slice in things.chunks(2) {
        println!("{:?}", slice);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
[5, 4]
[3, 2]
[1]
```

The *easiest* way to combine this with a `Range` would be to collect the range to a `Vec` first (which dereferences to a slice):

```
fn main() {
    let things: Vec<_> = (1..100).collect();

    for slice in things.chunks(5) {
        println!("{:?}", slice);
    }
}
```

Another solution that is pure-iterator would be to use [`Itertools::chunks_lazy`](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks_lazy):

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    for chunk in &(1..100).chunks_lazy(5) {
        for val in chunk {
            print!("{}, ", val);
        }
        println!("");
    }
}
```

Which suggests a similar solution that only requires the standard library:

```
fn main() {
    let mut range = (1..100).peekable();

    while range.peek().is_some() {
        for value in range.by_ref().take(5) {
            print!("{}, ", value);
        }
        println!("");
    }
}
```

One trick is that Ruby and Rust have different handling here, mostly centered around efficiency.

In Ruby `Enumerable` can create new arrays to stuff values in without worrying about ownership and return a new array each time (check with `this_slice.object_id`).

In Rust, allocating a new vector each time would be pretty unusual. Additionally, you can't easily return a reference to a vector that the iterator holds due to complicated lifetime concerns.

A solution that's very similar to Ruby's is:

```
fn main() {
    let mut range = (1..100).peekable();

    while range.peek().is_some() {
        let chunk: Vec<_> = range.by_ref().take(5).collect();

        println!("{:?}", chunk);
    }
}
```

Which *could* be wrapped up in a new iterator that hides the details:

```
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct InefficientChunks<I>
    where I: Iterator
{
    iter: Peekable<I>,
    size: usize,
}

impl<I> Iterator for InefficientChunks<I>
    where I: Iterator
{
    type Item = Vec<I::Item>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.iter.peek().is_some() {
            Some(self.iter.by_ref().take(self.size).collect())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

trait Awesome: Iterator + Sized {
    fn inefficient_chunks(self, size: usize) -> InefficientChunks<Self> {
        InefficientChunks {
            iter: self.peekable(),
            size: size,
        }
    }
}

impl<I> Awesome for I where I: Iterator {}

fn main() {
    for chunk in (1..100).inefficient_chunks(5) {
        println!("{:?}", chunk);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ranges don't have chunks, at least not in stable: `error: no method named 'chunks' found for type 'core::ops::Range<usize>' in the current scope`

Comment: @TrevorAlexander I apologize; I read a bit too fast! I added some alternates. You may want to add to your question what your goal is. In my experience, I've rarely needed just a bunch of numbers. It's possible that there's a better overall approach.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting into a vec can easily kill your performance. An approach similar to in the question is perfectly fine.

```rust
fn chunk_range(range: Range<usize>, chunk_size: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item=Range<usize>> {
    range.clone().step_by(chunk_size).map(move |block_start| {
        let block_end = (block_start + chunk_size).min(range.end);
        block_start..block_end
    })
}
```