# Alternative to Vec::chunks() that consumes the vector

Tags: vector, iterator, rust

I have the following function, which takes a vector as argument and returns a vector of its pairs of elements:

```
fn to_pairs(flat: Vec<u64>) -> Vec<(u64, u64)> {
    assert!(flat.len() % 2 == 0);
    let mut pairs = Vec::new();
    pairs.reserve(flat.len() / 2);
    for pair in flat.chunks(2) {
        assert!(pair.len() == 2);
        pairs.push((pair.get(0).unwrap().clone(), pair.get(1).unwrap().clone()));
    }
    pairs
}
```

I want consume the vector `flat` so I don't have to clone its elements when constructing the pair.
Is it possible to do so without reimplementing a variation of `Vec::chunks()` myself?

Comment: Do you want to use `unsafe`?

Comment: I would prefer not to.

Comment: Is it suitable if you use other structures like [numeric::Tensor](http://numeric.rs/doc/numeric/tensor/struct.Tensor.html), which supports reshaping?

Comment: They're `u64`s; there's no practical difference between cloning and moving them.

Comment: @kennytm That would require copying the data too, so no.

Comment: @DK. It's just to have a simple example. In practice I have structs.

Comment: @DK. It's possible to transmute the `Vec<u64>` into `Vec<(u64, u64)>` in O(1) time, there is a practical difference.

Comment: @kennytm That seems like a sure-fire way to break the `Vec`.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz If you only need pairs it should be trivial. Just `fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(T, T)> { match (self.next(), self.next()) { (Some(x), Some(x)) => Some((x, x)), _ => None } }` on the `Vec`'s iterator.

Comment: @kennytm I don't think that OP is asking about preserving the allocation *of the `Vec`*, but the allocation of the items contained *within the `Vec`*.

Answer (score 1):

> I want consume the vector `flat` so I don't have to clone its elements when constructing the pair.

Convert the input `Vec` into an iterator, then take two things from the iterator at a time. Essentially, you want the same thing as [processing a `Range` (an iterator) in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37033906/155423):

```
fn to_pairs<T>(flat: Vec<T>) -> Vec<(T, T)> {
    let len = flat.len();

    assert!(len % 2 == 0);
    let mut pairs = Vec::with_capacity(len / 2);

    let mut input = flat.into_iter().peekable();

    while input.peek().is_some() {
        match (input.next(), input.next()) {
            (Some(a), Some(b)) => pairs.push((a, b)),
            _ => unreachable!("Cannot have an odd number of values"),
        }
    }

    pairs
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(vec![(1,2), (3,4)], to_pairs(vec![1,2,3,4]));
    assert_eq!(vec![(true,true), (false,false)], to_pairs(vec![true,true,false,false]));
}
```

The `assert!(len % 2 == 0);` is quite important here, as `Iterator` makes no guarantees about what happens **after** the first time `next` returns `None`. Since we call `next` twice without checking the first value, we could be triggering that case. In other cases, you'd want to use [`fuse`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fuse).

As [pointed out by Kha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097395/alternative-to-vecchunks-that-consumes-the-vector/37099876?noredirect=1#comment61868686_37099876), you could simplify the `while` loop a bit:

```
let mut input = flat.into_iter();

while let (Some(a), Some(b)) = (input.next(), input.next()) {
    pairs.push((a, b));
}
```

Comment: You could replace `peek` with a `(None, None)` case